# Emoji typewriting animation via pure JavaScript cause rendering

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to recreate the idea of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POX3dT-pB4E) by creating a typewriting logo of the site that contains emojis. However, it seems that rendering emoji on browser takes a little while, so rhombus with a question mark appears for a moment.

[image: screen record here]

I believe that it's somehow connected with the nature of dec/hex rendering, but failed to find some detailed sources on the topic as I can't clearly state the problem. I would be very grateful for any ideas to resolve this problem.

My JS, CSS, and HTML respectively:

```js
// ES6 Class
class TypeWriter {
    constructor(txtElement, words, wait = 3000) {
      this.txtElement = txtElement;
      this.words = words;
      this.txt = '';
      this.wordIndex = 0;
      this.wait = parseInt(wait, 10);
      this.type();
      this.isDeleting = false;
    }
  
    type() {
      // Current index of word
      const current = this.wordIndex % this.words.length;
      // Get full text of current word
      const fullTxt = this.words[current];
  
      // Check if deleting
      if(this.isDeleting) {
        // Remove char
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
      } else {
        // Add char
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
      }
  
      // Insert txt into element
      this.txtElement.innerHTML = `<span class="txt">${this.txt}</span>`;
  
      // Initial Type Speed
      let typeSpeed = 300;
  
      if(this.isDeleting) {
        typeSpeed /= 2;
      }
  
      // If word is complete
      if(!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        // Make pause at end
        typeSpeed = this.wait;
        // Set delete to true
        this.isDeleting = true;
      } else if(this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        // Move to next word
        this.wordIndex++;
        // Pause before start typing
        typeSpeed = 500;
      }
  
      setTimeout(() => this.type(), typeSpeed);
    }
  }
  
  
  // Init On DOM Load
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
  
  // Init App
  function init() {
    const txtElement = document.querySelector('.txt-type');
    const words = JSON.parse(txtElement.getAttribute('data-words'));
    const wait = txtElement.getAttribute('data-wait');
    // Init TypeWriter
    new TypeWriter(txtElement, words, wait);
  }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400');
/* https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/ typewritting effect */

:root{
  --header-height: 2rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  font-family: Raleway;
  color: rgb(42, 42, 42);
}

.nav__logo {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(42, 42, 42);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="nav__logo"><b>@alexpoov </b></a>
  <span class="nav__logo txt-type" data-wait="3000" data-words='["&#127803;", "&#129337;", "&#9996;", "&#x1F4BB;", "&#x2614;", "&#127929;", "&#128248;", "&#129305;"]'> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: All you want is it to switch between the emojis?

Comment: @skara9 yes, and in addition to emoji, I want to print spaces before and after them, and show the cursor so that it looks like real printing. I wish there is some solution to make this switch smooth, without question rhombus rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to change the emoji, the code you have overcomplicates it.

Attempting to change as little of your existing code as possible, the example below should show the emoji for 800ms and hide it for 500ms.

```js
class TypeWriter {
  constructor(txtElement, words) {
    this.txtElement = txtElement;
    this.words = words;
    this.wordIndex = 0;
    this.type(true); // show at the beginning
  }

  type(show) { // added 'show' param to determine whether to show or hide emoji
    if (!show) {
      this.txtElement.innerText = '';
      setTimeout(() => this.type(true), 500); // wait 500ms and show
      return;
    }
    this.txtElement.innerText = this.words[this.wordIndex];
    this.wordIndex++;
    this.wordIndex %= this.words.length;
    setTimeout(() => this.type(false), 800); // wait 800ms and hide
  }
}
```

---

If you want a pseudo-cursor object in place, you can add something like this after the emoji:

```html
<span class="nav__logo cursor">|</span>
```

You can style it how you wish.

Comment: My solution were played on string before, didn't change it. Thank you for the answer! But I still can't understand why you've got no rendering emojis, while I had.

Comment: @AlexPopov your emoji is made up of 2 individual characters, so the 'typing' animation involved splitting it in half at one point